# Multiple args.split().join(" ") discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js, args

So I am making a discord bot using Discord.js. In the bot, there is a command where you can do a giveaway ping and the bot will send a embed with the sponsor, prize, and message. But I need all of these different arguments to have args.slice().join(" ").

```
    const Discord = require('discord.js');
    module.exports = {
        name: 'giveaway',
        description: 'giveaway embed',
        execute(message, args) {

            if(!message.member.hasPermission("MENTION_EVERYONE")) return message.channel.send('You do not have permission to do this!');
        
            let sponsor = args[0];
            if(!sponsor) {
                sponsor = 'Me';
            }

            let prize = args.slice(1).split('/').join(" ");
            if(!prize) return message.reply('You need to put a prize for the giveaway! `-giveaway <sponsor> <prize> <message>`');

            let userMessage = args.slice(2).join(' ')
            if(!userMessage) {
                userMessage = 'none';
            }
                const giveawayPingEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle(':tada: GIVEAWAY :tada:')
                .setDescription(`Sponsor: ${sponsor} \nPrize: ${prize} \nMessage: ${userMessage}`)

                
            
        },
    };
```

Comment: Please be more specific about the problem. What is it that not working? What is it that you want? Examples?

Comment: Can you please also give an example of usage? How does the command look when you write it in discord? That will help to determine how things should be split up, thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: so when you do the command the bot would send this:

@giveaway ping

Sponsor: <args[0]>

Prize: <args[1]>

Message: <args[2]>

So what I need to do is do so you can have multiple words for each variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you asked for another way, here it is:

```js
var X = args.join(" ") //X is your message arguments - change it depending on how you run them
if (!X) return message.channel.send("Error - No arguments");

var sponsor = X.replace(new RegExp('.*' + "sponsor:"), ''); //uses regex to remove text after the word "sponsor:"
var prize = sponsor.replace(new RegExp('.*' + "prize:"), '');
var messageUser = sponsor.replace(new RegExp('.*' + "message:"), '');
sponsor = sponsor.replace(prize, "").replace("prize:", "")
prize = prize.replace(messageUser, "").replace("message:", "") //removes parts you dont want

message.channel.send(sponsor);
message.channel.send(prize);
message.channel.send(messageUser);
```

Please note I have not input validated

Syntax MUST be `<prefix><command name> sponsor: <sponsor name> prize: <prize> message: <message>`

e.g.:

```
!giveaway sponsor: @user prize: epic prize message: epic message
```

Comment: Hi, so when I pasted in the code here and ran it, it said X is not defined.

Comment: I forgot an important part, sorry ^ this WILL work now

Comment: Again, Thank you for the help... So incase I wanted to use this again for a different command, how would I change what the arguments you pass in would be. For example instead of it being !giveaway sponsor: @user prize: epic prize message: epic message

it could be something else like username, and suggestion

Comment: Have 2 variables, username and suggestion, keep X the same. Instead of `"sponsor:"` in the RegExp, change it to username. Do the same with the suggestion variable. Then, instead of `sponsor = sponsor.replace(prize, "").replace("prize:", "")` simply change it to `username = username.replace("suggestion", "").replace("suggestion:", "")`

Comment: okay, now this is probably related to something completely else, but how would I do like in some commands where they split the arguments with a "/" because I saw in a different discord server that they had a similar command where they split the arguments with a /

Comment: just use an `args.split("/")`

Comment: so would I do for example prize = args.split("/").join(" ")?

Answer (score 0):

You could use iterated message collectors to fill out a form - since deciding when 1 message stops and another starts is difficult in your situation.

```js
let input = []; // declare input as empty array
let setupQ = ['Sponsor:', 'Prize', 'Message'];

async function giveaway(){
   for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
     message.channel.send(setupQ[i]);   

     const filter = (user) => {
         return user.author.id === message.author.id //only collects messages from the user who sent the command
     };

     try{
     let collected = await message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 1, time: 15000, errors: ['time'] });
        input[i] = collected.first().content; //takes user input and saves it
      }
     catch(e)
      {
         return message.channel.send(`:x: Setup cancelled - 0 messages were collected in the time limit, please try again`).then(m => m.delete({ timeout: 4000 }));
      };              
   };
};

giveaway(); //calls the async function to start the giveaway form
```

This code will send the `inputQ` questions incrementally, and save the responses to the `input` array. If you are unfamiliar with `async/await`, please look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Introducing)

Please look at message collector syntax and functions [here](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html)

Comment: Hey Joe Moore, thanks for helping me out on this. It works but, the only problem is I kind of need it to be all in one sentence. So if there is a way to do this I would really appreciate it. Other than that, it worked perfectly!

Comment: @NoReflection You have a problem unfortunately, which is it is very difficult to identify where arguments in your message start and end e.g. how does the bot know where the prize ends and the sponsor begins? I can't think of any other way to do it other than add in physical words in the message e.g. `!giveaway sponsor: @user prize: example message: example` - but that would be clunky and slow. My way is probably the best way to do it.

Comment: Yes your way is definitely the best way to do it. Its just they user is meant to host a giveaway with a bot and then send that command all in one go.

Comment: @NoReflection I could do it in the way I described but it would be much slower, alot easier to do it the way above, but let me know

Comment: Yep, I would like to know how to do it for future references. Thanks for the help earlier By the way!